# How to send file using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I am trying to make an upload page which takes file to upload. I am using Spring framework here my query is on Upload button I am calling a JavaScript method which should send my file to controller using jQuery AJAX. Is there any way to pass this through JavaScript?

Following is the code which I am trying.

```
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 60px;">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select file:
            <input type="file" name="dataFile" id="fileAttachment"/><br/><br/>
                <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 100px;">
                    <input style="cursor: pointer;" onmouseover="" onclick="uploadAttachment()" class="dialogbox" type="submit" value="Upload Report" />
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
<script language="Javascript">
function uploadAttachment(){
    var Name = jQuery('#Name option:selected').text();
    jQuery.post('upload',{Name:Name}
    function(data){
    if(data==1)
    alert("success");
    else
    alert("failed");
    });
}
    </script>
```

> on controller.java page following is the code written

```
@RequestMapping(value = "upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody String upload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
@RequestParam("Name") String Name){
System.out.println(Name);
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want.Do you want to show the uploaded file detail in the same page ? Just like `gmail` shows the attachment details ?

Comment: i just want to send the file selected for upload to controller via Jquery.post()

Comment: Can you post your controller code ?

Comment: @HumanBeing : above i pasted the example of my controller where i am sending String object to controller, now is there any way to send file object to controller ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in fact seeking a pure javascript way to upload an image/file, then the following tutorial from 2009 will tell you exactly how to do that:

http://igstan.ro/posts/2009-01-11-ajax-file-upload-with-pure-javascript.html

I ran into this when I wanted to add basic-authentication to a form submission, without enabling cookies. E.g. when you have username/password fields with your filename, file, etc fields.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the following code to upload file with javascript.

```
function uploadAttachment(){
  $('#fileAttachment').trigger('click');

  if (typeof timer != 'undefined') {
      clearInterval(timer);
  }

  timer = setInterval(function() {
      if ($('#fileAttachment').val() != '') {
          clearInterval(timer);

          $.ajax({
              url: 'YOUR_UPLOAD_URL',
              type: 'post',
              dataType: 'json',
              data: new FormData($('#fileAttachment').closest('form')[0]),
              cache: false,
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,
              success: function(response){
              }
          });
      }
  }, 500);
}
```

You need to replace `YOUR_UPLOAD_URL` with your server upload URL.